# When specifying fe panel quantile regression in R should I use as.factor(ID) in place of s in - fit <- rqpd(y ~ x | s, panel(lambda = 5)), or id

Tags: r

On the forum, when some people post their queries related to panel quantile regression, they use only 'ID' to in the command: fit <- rqpd(y ~ x | s, panel(lambda = 5)), whereas some people use factor(ID) or as.factor(ID). In my case, the model gives me the error 'Error in .local(x, ...) : Increase tmpmax' when I use factor(ID) or as.factor(ID). what does the error mean? and, what is the correct way of performing panel quantile regression with fixed effects in R?

I was trying panel quantile regression by using command rqpd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `ID` is numeric then `... | ID` will fit a slope, whereas `... | as.factor(ID)` will fit an intercept per unique value. These are not the same models, though only you can judge which one is most relevant (I am guessing it's the multiple intercepts one). `rqpd` does not fit an overall intercept for the panel structure effect.

The error itself actually comes from `quantreg::rq.fit.sfn`, and as the documentation for `rqpd` explains that fitting routine can be tweaked via the `control` argument as a wrapper for `quantreg::sfn.control`. Try including `control = quantreg::sfn.control(tmpmax = XXX)` in your `rqpd` call, where you can increase `XXX` until the error hopefully disappears. The default for this argument is six times the number of columns in your overall design matrix (fixed + panel).

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification. I wanted to understand how I can modify my rqpd call? Do you mean I need to change the default rqpd code? if so, how is that done? 

I appreciate your help!

Comment: I figured! Thanks a ton for the suggestion!